# helm install prometheus pvc not able to claim from pv

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I created 2 pv on a usb drive with:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: prometheus-alertmanager
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 4Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  storageClassName: prometheus-alertmanager
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/tinkerext/Prometheus
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: prometheus-server
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 14Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  storageClassName: prometheus-server
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/tinkerext/Prometheus
---
```

after that, i tried to use helm to install prometheus in the default namespace with `helm install prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus --version 15.5.4` as mentioned in [helm prometheus](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/prometheus?modal=install)

immediately after a successful install, i am met with issues with `prometheus-alertmanager` and `prometheus-server`. I checked that it was because of unbound persistentvolumeclaim.

My question is, I have been trying to get prometheus to claim the pv that i have created, but no luck there.

I even inspected prometheus values with `helm get values prometheus > helm-prometheus.yaml` and made changes to the below: (by adding storageClassName)

```
---
# Source: prometheus/templates/alertmanager/pvc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    component: "alertmanager"
    app: prometheus
    release: release-name
    chart: prometheus-15.5.4
    heritage: Helm
  name: release-name-prometheus-alertmanager
  namespace: default
spec:      
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "2Gi"
  storageClassName: prometheus-alertmanager
---
# Source: prometheus/templates/server/pvc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    component: "server"
    app: prometheus
    release: release-name
    chart: prometheus-15.5.4
    heritage: Helm
  name: release-name-prometheus-server
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "8Gi"
  storageClassName: prometheus-server
```

But this still doesn't work. How should I be correctly specifying for prometheus to claim the PV that I have created?

Note: I updated my helm after editing it with `helm upgrade -f helm-prometheus.yaml prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus`

Comment: Are those storageClasses valid? `prometheus-alertmanager` and `prometheus-server`.
What is the output of `$ kubectl get storageclass`?

Comment: hi, interesting.. `k get storageclass` returns empty. `no resources found`. but `k get pv` shows that i have `pv` set up

Comment: FYI - i am using hostPath to a local hard drive. how should it be done?

Comment: You probably shouldn't create a PersistentVolume at all.  If you create a PersistentVolumeClaim (or if the Helm chart creates a StatefulSet that has PVCs) then normally the cluster should have a [dynamic provisioner](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#dynamic) that creates the underlying storage.  A `hostPath` volume is usually wrong since it points at a named directory on whichever host the pod happens to run on, which can cause data to get misplaced if a pod gets deleted and recreated on a different node.